# What is the graph of $-2^{-|x|}$?

Tags: calculus, functions

What is its graph? 
Please explain how to obtain it.

THANKS.

Comment: Try investigating the $x\geq 0$ and $x<0$ cases separately.

Comment: Do you want the graph of $-2^{-|x|}$ or of $(-2)^{-|x|}$ ?

Comment: Qualitatively, it shouldn't differ much from the $-e^{-\vert{x}\vert}$ graph. Do you know that graph, at the very least?

Comment: @BernardMassé ... A mathematician means $-(2^{-|x|})$ by this.  Surely this problem also does.  If you have $(-2)^{-|x|}$, involving irrational powers of negative numbers, they will in general be complex. So an elementary textbook would not ask for the graph of it in that case.

Comment: @GEdgar   Well one answer given and accepted  is for $(-2)^{-|x|}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can just plug in numbers to your function! (I'll be assuming you mean $(-2)^{-|x|}$ but you can do this for the other form of this function.)

So we plug in -5, we get -5 for the exponent, and -2  to the -5 is -0.03125. We can plug in -2, we get -2, and -2 to the -2 is -0.25. We can plug in 0, and we get 0 for the exponent; -2 to the 0 is 1. If we plug in 2 we get -0.25, if we plug in 5, we get -0.03125.

We know a few things from this exercise:

1. The graph is symmetric across the y-axis.
2. On both sides of the y-axis, as $x$ approaches $-\infty$ or $\infty$, $y$ approaches $0$.
3. We also know a few points on the graph.

We can now make a quick sketch of the graph, knowing these things:

[image]

As we know more points, the better the graph will get.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 8):

1) $y=2^x$
[image]

2) $y=2^{-x}$

[image]

3) $y=2^{-|x|}$

[image]

4) $y=-2^{-|x|}$

[image]